# AT&T Samsung Galaxy Skyrocket running jellybean update, Voice Dialer issues with BlueAnt

Tags: bluetooth, phone-app, voice-command, voice-recognition

I upgraded my phone using KIES through a USB connection and now when ever I try to use my BlueAnt Q2 bluetooth headset it starts the new Voice Dialler that just doesn't work at all. Can't recognize a word I say and then takes off dialing a number that's not even close to what I have said. Is there any solution to this or am I just hosed..